# Microsoft GUID serialization using boost serialize?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, guid

I have the following:

```
struct Member
{
    GUID id;
    int extra;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        ar & id;
        ar & extra;
    }

}
```

When I compile the code I get the following compile error:

**Error 25  error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of '_GUID'**

How do I specialise boost serialization for Microsoft GUID?

Comment: [Just RTFM](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html), follow the example for the non-intrusive version.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: assuming the `UUID` type is POD, you can use `make_binary_object`.

Here's a mockup type for `UUID` as a POD:

```
#include <array>

using UUID = std::array<uint8_t, 16>; // mock up
static_assert(std::is_pod<UUID>(), "assumes UUID is POD");
```

Any POD will do. E.g. `boost::uuids::uuid`¹ is also POD. Same for `struct UUID { char data[16]; }` etc.

### Non-intrusive serialization:

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, UUID& u, unsigned /*version*/) {
            ar & make_binary_object(&u, sizeof(u));
        }
} }
```

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6454e4331273c495)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
        UUID u {{0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f}};
        oa << u;
    }

    std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";

    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        UUID u {};
        ia >> u;

        std::copy(begin(u), end(u), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout << "roundtripped: ", " "));
    }
}
```

---

¹ although that library already defines serialization in the `boost/uuid/uuid_serialize.hpp` header